# Laravel Query builder: left join, select, and where not working

Tags: sql, laravel

Unfortunately the Laravel query builder seems not in a good mood!

Here is my table structure:

Table `user` structure

```
ID, USERNAME, NAME, USER_ROLE_MODULE_ID
```

Table `user_role_module` structure

```
ID, NAME
```

And this is my query builder statement

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('user_role_module', 'user.user_role_module_id', '=', 'user_role_module.id')
->select('user.*', 'user_role_module.name as user_role')
->where("name LIKE '%Jhon%' ") "or other example" ->where("user_role LIKE '%admin%' ")
->paginate(10);
```

**Goal:**

I just want to get all data from `user` + user role name from `user_role_module` AND also applies in WHERE statement so I can use it for search feature.

I am getting result from WHERE statement without specifying table name. because it already stated which table and column to select from SELECT statement.

**The problem:**

1. if I search for name, it return error ambiguous column //Laravel is confusing whether taking `name` from user table or user_role_module table!
2. if I search for user_role, then the column doesn't exist

Why is it? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('user_role_module', 'user.user_role_module_id', '=', 'user_role_module.id')
->select('user.*', 'user_role_module.name as user_role')
->where("name LIKE '%Jhon%' ") "or other example" ->where("user_role LIKE '%admin%' ")
->paginate(10);
```

with this:

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('user_role_module', 'user.user_role_module_id', '=', 'user_role_module.id')
->where('user.name', 'like', '%Jhon%')
->select('user.*', 'user_role_module.name as user_role')
->get();
```

and make a custom pagination because select is not working with paginate.

Comment: Sorry friend, I made mistake in my question, I have edited it. I think nothing wrong with my leftJoin @Viktor Maksimov

Comment: Yes, in case of searching for `name` it works perfectly.Thanks, but when I search for `user_role` which is aliases is still resulting error. 
Btw. is there a way to select something without specifying table name? Because I want to make it dynamic. @Viktor Maksimov

Comment: @Angger you should not search for `user_role` because `->select` should be after `->where`. You should search for `->where('user_role_module.name', 'like', '%admin%')` and then `->select()`

Comment: If my search feature is dynamic table, means, it can be select from user or user_role_module table, what is the solution? is there other way to not to select with specific table or just by column selected? @Viktor Maksimov

Comment: You should make this: `->where('user.name', 'like', '%Jhon%')->orWhere('user_role_module.name', 'like', '%admin%')` and so on. Please approve and vote for my answer if it have helped you.

Comment: It return error : unknown 'user_role_module.user_role', what I concern is to get column user_role column @Viktor Maksimov

Comment: it should be `'user_role_module.name'`, because in your table `user_role_module` the column is `name` and not `user_role`. Don't forget that `select` statement is executing after `where`. Please make a chat if your problem continues.

Comment: I don't think your error is due to the join, but rather due to that both tables have a `NAME` column.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:**

```
user.NAME                 <-- both these columns are called NAME
user_role_module.NAME     <--
```

You have multiple problems with your Laravel query.  As @Viktor correctly pointed out, your join condition is wrong.  You should be joining `user.USER_ROLE_MODULE_ID` to `user_role_module.id`.  But the immediate cause of your error I believe is that both tables have a `NAME` column.

Just specify the columns you want using both table *and* column name.  This way, no column name would be ambiguous.

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('user_role_module', 'user.USER_ROLE_MODULE_ID', '=', 'user_role_module.id')
->select('user.ID', 'user.USERNAME', 'user.NAME AS userName',
         'user_role_module.name as user_role')
->where("name LIKE '%John%'")
->paginate(10);
```